# Passport req.user returns CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ _id: 'me', active: true }" at path "_id" for model "user"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, passport.js, passport-local

i'm trying to do the users login persistent with Passport, actually i can login in my app,
but when i try to persist the login using req.user, in the client  console it returns me html code and in the Postman console it returns **CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ _id: 'me', active: true }" at path "_id" for model "user"**.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKB6G.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQMAq.png)

i used passport-local for several times, but it's the first one that i used it with a mongoAtlas db, i don't know if it make sense but i mentioned it

My passport config:

```
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => done(null, user.id));

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) =>
    User.findById(id)
      .then((user) => done(null, user)) // req.user = user
      .catch(done)
  );

passport.use(
  new LocalStrategy(
    {
      usernameField: "email",
      passwordField: "password",
    }, function(email, password, done){
      User.findOne({ email })
          .then(user => {
            if(!user) return done(null, false)

            user.comparePassword(password, (err, isMatch) => {
              if(err) throw err;
              if(!isMatch) return done(null, false);
              return done(null, user)
            })
          })
          .catch(done);
    }
  )
 )
```

Routes and Controllers:

```
router.post("/login",passport.authenticate("local"), UserController.login)
router.post("/logout", UserController.logout)
router.get("/me", UserController.check) // <-----route to persist

//----------------Controllers-----------------------------
login(req, res, next){
    console.log(req.user);
     res.send(req.user)
  },
  logout(req, res, next){
    req.logOut()
    res.sendStatus(200)
  },
  check(req, res, next){ 
    if(req.user)return res.send(req.user)
      res.sendStatus(401)
    }
```

Github repo: https://github.com/seriann/writeYourTabs

Comment: if your problem is not solved, leave a comment, if my answer is true accept it, thank you

Answer (score 1):

your request is `.../api/users/me` your route in server is `.../api/users/:id`, so `me` is `id` after that you use this in `usersController`:

```
  findById(req,res,next){
    User.findById({_id:req.params.id, active:true})
        .then(user => res.send(user))
        .catch(err => next(err))
  },
```

when you want to use `findById()` you must to pass a mongoose `objectId()` not a `String`,
so can use `findOne()` or pass a objectId to `findById()`

Comment: Ow, so my routes "/api/users/:id" were colliding with "/api/users/me", thanks!